# How to create a separate lines plot in SPSS syntax?

Tags: plot, graph, syntax, spss

I know how to solve the problem in the SPSS interface. I am not sure how to do it in the SPSS command syntax.

I have data in within subjects design, with three different levels.

```
GRAPH /LINE= MEAN(ct, cbt, psycanal).
```

ct, cbt, psycanal are the names of the within subjects levels. I also have a gender variable, which I want to use to create separate plots. The above syntax produces a line of means through the three levels of the within-subjects independent variables.

Does anybody know how to add a command to create separate plots for gender. Just adding `BY GENDER` does not help unfortunately, because this specify the X-axis variable.

Comment: When you say "separate plots," just how separate do you mean?  The SPLIT FILE command (either layered or not) might do what you're looking for.

Comment: Separate plots on the same graph. No split file would not help here, since I can already use the gender variable. I could do two plots with your suggestion, but I want them on the same graph.

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure I understand what you want but it seems to me that it is someting like this:

```
GRAPH 
/LINE (MULTIPLE)  = MEAN(ct, cbt, psycanal)  BY SEX.
```

For multiple lines you need the keyword `(MULTIPLE)`  and the default is `(SIMPLE)`

Comment: This puts the gender on the x-axis which is not what I want.

Comment: @BorutFlis perhaps you should explain what you want more accurately. This was the most logical adaptation of your code. It would be nice if you could attach a picture of what you want to get.